# SwiftUI: Strange behavior with Tabbar

Tags: swiftui, uitabbar

My App has a TabBar with 3 bar items, as follows

```
var body: some View {
    TabView() {
        NavigationView {
            View1()
        }
        .tabItem { Label("Tab1"), systemImage: "calendar.badge.exclamationmark") }
        
        View2()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Tab2"), systemImage: "list.bullet")
            }
        
        View3()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Tab3"), systemImage: "info")
            }
    }
}
```

What I do not understand is why Tab2 appears 2 times, it means I have in total 4 tabs instead of 3.
I am feeling quite stupid :-)

Comment: Would you show `View2`? Probably you have a Group at top there.

Comment: Yes I would like to have View2; it appears, but twice (I mean, twice the tab item); the first has the correct View2 inside, the second one is empty

Comment: @MarcoGT When I remove the `)` for the `Label`s so it compiles, I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: You have additional parenthesis in your Labels as @George_E states. Removing them fixes the problem and makes the issue irreproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a couple misplaced parentheses `()` that might have been the problem. Try this code (replace `Text("View one")` with `View1()` and so on):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                Text("View one")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Tab1", systemImage: "calendar.badge.exclamationmark")

            }

            Text("View two")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab2", systemImage: "list.bullet")

                }

            Text("View three")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab3", systemImage: "info")

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: 3 tabs]